# How much does the 'Notched Pickaxe' Improve Smithing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I found this Easter Egg after reading Notch's (The creator of Minecraft) [Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/135958555214876672).

One of the stats is that it improves Smithing, however it does not state by how much. I can not seem to find any difference at all, when creating new armors and weapons.

Also, would it be worth disenchanting it, and apply the effect to more of my stuff?

Comment: "Raises the wielders Smithing ability, and does X shock damamge to enemies on hit." I guess it's gramatically ambiguous, but my impression is it "raises the wielders Smithing ability ... on hit" -- you get the bonus when you use it in combat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just climbed Skyrim's tallest mountain for you. The notched pickaxe increases smithing by five.

It is not leveled loot, and does not stack.

Comment: Huh, the EUSP says it increases it by 5. I'll have to test this myself when I get home.

Comment: How can you tell how much it increases in-game?

Comment: @AllanJensen Go to the Skills / Perks screen with it equipped and if it has an effect Smithing's skill number should show up in green.

Comment: @AllanJensen Go to your magic menu and look under 'Active Effects'

Comment: @Allan Just picked it up and updated my answer.

Comment: I have not noticed any improvement in smithing. I equipped the pick with 71 smithing skill and it remained at 71

Answer (score 2):

Under active effects it says that it increases your smithing skill by 5. As far as I can tell, it doesn't - My Daedric Armor goes from 90 to 120 armor after workbenching it, regardless if I have the pickaxe equipped or not. My smithing level remains at 90, equipped or not.
Conclusion: Either they removed the buff while keeping the text in the latest patch, or it only gives you smithing if your smithing is low.

Comment: I think it just buffs the smithing level by 5 meaning when you go to your skills, it will increase the overall skill by 5.

This may essentially allow you to get the 100 smithing perk with 95+5 skill.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, it doesn't work, it doesn't affect your stats or skills, and does nothing in terms of creating new things.

Comment: No smithing skill affects creating new things because creating always gives you the "base object". Smithing affects improving items, so the Notched Pickaxe only affects improving too.

Answer (score -1):

The enchantment only restores your smithing when damaged, according to the UESP page on the enchantment itself

Comment: It seems that information was wrong and edited out as [it no longer appears on the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Notched_Pickaxe).