# How do I get the Notched Pickaxe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A friend told me that he had a Notched Pickaxe what will give you smithing levels if you mine so I wanted to know how I could get it.

Comment: FYI, your friend is wrong about [what the pickaxe does](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36499), just so you're not disappointed when you find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to climb to the peak of the Throat of the World. There you will find the Notched Pickaxe sticking out of a stone.

Comment: Please summarize what's happening in the video; if it gets removed, then there's nothing here to help anyone.

Comment: @fbueckert did it, could you please take back your downvote?

Comment: What mountain?  Your directions still rely on the video being available.

Comment: @fbueckert Throat of the World IS a mountain.... everyone playing Skyrim knows that...

Comment: @Ekonion Maybe mention that it is east of riverwoood, south east of whiterun and visited during the story quests.

Comment: @ColinD No, that's not necessary. If someone doesn't know where the Throat of the World is, they simply haven't played the game. (It would be like needing to explain that there is snow in Skyrim, or dragons.)

Comment: @ColinD … "Skipped most of the talking parts" … Like I said, if someone doesn't know where the Throat of the World is, they simply haven't played the game. I suppose it's technically possible to never realise there are dragons in the game too, but we don't cater to the <0.1% of people who have extremely abnormal playthroughs or deliberately ignore what's on-screen. They can use google to find out basic things like "What is the throat of the world", or they can watch the video. If we have to say it's east of Riverwood, do we have to explain where Riverwood is too?

Answer (score 1):

It's found at the top of Throat of the World. You need to do the main quest to get access. At the top is the Notched Pickaxe which Fortify's Smithing by 5 points. It's rather a reference to Notch, creater of Minecraft and co-founder of Mojang, or 2 mountain climbers who got lost and people found evidence of there whereabouts by finding a mark.